# WatchKit context menu, how to tell which row it was for?

Tags: xcode6, contextmenu, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacetable

I have a `WKInterfaceTable` in my interface controller and have added a Context Menu to the controller. On tap holding a specific row, the row depresses and displays the context menu. How do I know what row the menu is for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context menu is for the entire view, it has no concept of where you tapped.

Comment: Then why does it press and depress a single row when you tap and hold?

Comment: I've never seen it do that, I'm just telling you what I know to be true. Here's the line from the HIG: "Do not create an action that affects only the selected item or only a portion of your interface. Actions apply to the entire screen."

Comment: Sucks man. Yeah it bounces the row up and down as if the context menu came out from that row. That's misleading.

Answer (score -1):

The following gets called on your `WKInterfaceController`.

```
- (void)table:(WKInterfaceTable *)table didSelectRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)rowIndex
```

Comment: No it does not. Not on a tap-hold gesture for the context menu to appear. This is only called on a simple tap.

Comment: Doh, sorry I misunderstood your question.  There is no way to detect a force press.  So unfortunately, you can't do that.